Flask with pywebview cannot find templates
I'm running a properly working Flask website.
Templates are in the proper location /templates
When adding python webview (https://pywebview.flowrl.com/), like:
app = Flask(__name__)
webview.create_window('Some title', app)

it runs perfectly from PyCharm IDE. But after:
pyinstaller -F -w --icon=cpnits-picto.ico --name Butterfly main.py

the standalone cannot find the templates. Standalone runs fine, does all it should do, also gives output when not using templates (for testing purposes). But it does not find the templates.
I've tried things like:
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./static', template_folder='./templates') 

and adding all sorts of paths to it. No success.
What am I doing wrong?
The complete code of a minimized test project that gives the same error:
from flask import Flask, render_template
import webview

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_error(e):
    return f'<h1>Error</h1><p>{e}</p>', 500

webview.create_window('Doei', app)
webview.start()
# pyinstaller -F -w --name TWV main.py

Where the template index.html is in the dir templates.
Thanks to the handle_error(e) the name of the error appears in the webviewer.

I was indeed (thanks Farrukh) looking in the wrong place. Problem was not Flask or Webview, but PyInstaller.

This problem is very common while we use the PyInstaller along with Flask. You will need to include templates and static folder while you are packing application.
Note for Windows you might need to semicolon
pyinstaller -F -w --add-data "templates:templates" --name Butterfly main.py 

Next simply specify the templates in .spec file using datas parameter.

Thanks Farrukh! You solved my problem.
The full pyinstaller line for making a standalon app named Butterfly, not opening the terminal, adding an icon and including both templates and static folders is:
pyinstaller -F -w --noconfirm --clean --add-data templates:templates --add-data static:static --icon=cpnits-picto.ico --name Butterfly main.py
No additional parameters or .spec files required.
